# vertical navigation with rotated text

Tags: css, navigation, vertical-alignment, navigationbar

I am trying to achieve a vertical navigation menu which has links and I have rotated the links text to 270 degree with css3. I have rotated it because I wanted the text to be bottom to top. The problem is when I add a padding top it is getting inconsistent spacing. you can see my code [here](http://jsbin.com/ravuduni/1/edit). I am unable to understand the different space being taken. I also tried giving li a height but it did not work. Please if someone could help me out. Here is my code:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="main-nav">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">METHODOLGY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TEAM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
 </div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.rotate{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);-moz-transform:rotate(270deg);-o-transform:rotate(270deg);writing-mode:lr-tb}
html, body {
  min-height:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  height:100%;
  font-family:Oswald, sans-serif, Arial;
  font-size:14px;
  background:#fff
}
a {
  text-decoration:none
}
li {
  list-style:none
}
ul {
  padding:0;
  margin:0
}
.main-nav {
  width:45px;
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;
  background:#4c4c4c
}
ul.nav {
  width:21px;
  margin:0 auto
}
ul.nav li:first-child {
  padding-top:35px
}
ul.nav li {
  padding-top:124px
}
ul.nav li a {
  -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(270deg);
  writing-mode:lr-tb;
  float:left;
  width:21px;
  color:#fff
}
```

Comment: I would rotate the outer `div` instead, you can try this demo http://jsbin.com/ravuduni/2

Comment: This seems perfect and I am thankful to you that you helped me out. I just want to ask a few things as I am unaware of them. what does this property do translateX(-100%) and what is vh in width: 100vh; And Please make this as your answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Rotating each `a` element or `li` element will make us encounter some problem spacing, positioning the elements exactly as we want. We should build the navigation menu so that it spreads horizontally, looks OK first then we just to need rotate the whole container of the navigation menu. Here is the updated code:

```
.main-nav {
  width:100vh;    
  height:45px;
  position:fixed;
  background:#4c4c4c;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%);
}
ul.nav li {    
  margin-right:20px;
  float:right;
  height:100%;
  line-height:45px;
}
```

The menu is supposed to have fixed height of `45px` (after rotated, it will be the width). We use `line-height:45px` to center the `a` element vertically (after rotated, it will be *horizontally*). At first the `.main-nav` will lie horizontally like this:

[image]

we need to rotate it `-90deg` (which is counter-clockwise) around the point `left - top` specified by `transform-origin: left top`. After rotated, all the `.main-nav` will be out of view like this:

[image]

So we need to translate it down a distance of `100% of width`, however note that we don't use `translateY` which seems to mean translate it vertically, because after rotated, the X axis becomes **vertical** (not horizontal as before), so we have to use `translateX(-100%)` (the positive direction is upwards, it's rightwards before rotated). Then we have:

[image]

It's just a simple use case related to transform in CSS3. For the `vh` unit, it's the unit relative to the viewport's height. `100vh` means `100% of viewport's height`. We have to use `100vh` for the `width` because after rotated, `width` becomes `height`. It should fill the full height of the viewport. However you can set some `min-width` for the `width` **by px** to limit the `width`'s minimum value. It's because when you resize the window, the viewport's height may become small and hence the `width` will be shrunk accordingly. Also note that instead of using `float:left` for the `li` elements, we have to use `float:right` so that the ***Home*** menu appears first from top to bottom, otherwise (using `float:left`), the ***Home*** menu will appear at the end (at bottom). There is a little advanced usage of the `transform` here (to newbie) it we use more than 1 transform for a `transform` property, all the transforms are separated by space and the order of transforms is important. Such as `rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%)` means rotating `-90deg` first, then translating along the X axis `-100%`, while `translateX(-100%) rotate(-90deg)` is reverse to that, it's a totally different thing and of course won't work (makes an unexpected result).

### [Jsbin Demo.](http://jsbin.com/ravuduni/11/)

Comment: Thank you for your help and the time you spent to explain these things for and that to in a very detailed manner. There are are only a few like you. As a newbie I have learnt a lot from you and I am sure I will improve by time. Thanks

Comment: @fahad.kazi you're welcome, for the downvote, next time just try posting your code in the question added with some demo link. Downvoting in this site is just a normal thing, it just helps the asker ask better next time, it does not mean people's hate or dislike to the asker, but **to the question** s/he asked :)

Comment: Yes I think that because I did not post my code I got downvoted. I will keep that in mind. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the importance of the order in the transform-property :)