# Vertical align with scrollable rotated text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a vertical navigation list, which is rotated 90 degrees to be become vertically scrollable(in relation to the viewport). The idea is that menu items can be added dynamically and once added should become scrollable vertically once the full viewport height has been used.

The current solution almost works, it makes the list expand horizontally which is not ideal if you have a narrow fixed width navigation bar.

Here is a code sample from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870696/vertical-navigation-with-rotated-text/23885539#23885539) from 2 years ago for illustration.

[JSBIN](http://output.jsbin.com/ravuduni/11/)

```css
html, body {
  min-height:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  height:100%;
  font-family:Oswald, sans-serif, Arial;
  font-size:14px;
  background:#fff
}
a {
  text-decoration:none
}
li {
  list-style:none
}
ul {    
  margin:0
}
.main-nav {
  width:100vh;    
  height:45px;
  position:fixed;
  background:#4c4c4c;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%);
}
ul.nav {    
  margin:0 auto;
  height:100%;        
}

ul.nav li {    
  margin-right:20px;
  float:right;
  height:100%;
  line-height:45px;
}
ul.nav li a {           
  color:#fff;    
}
```

```html
<div class="main-nav">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">METHODOLGY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TEAM</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You must include the transform property for other browser like firefox and the generic one too like `-moz-transform-origin: left top;
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%);` and `transform-origin: left top;
transform:rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%);`

Comment: It only works in chrome/safari, I don't know if it's your requirements, but them are weird requirements.

Comment: @geeksal generic works with firefox, chrome and IE in latest versions, in this case `-webkit-` prefix is specifically to safari

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I know but i am using firefox how i will test it if he does not include the above property

Comment: Me too. I use firefox by default always. Best browser ever (even when google make a lot of anti-firefox people)

Comment: @Jonker check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `display:flex` in `ul.nav` selector and set `overflow-y:hidden` and `overflow-x:auto` in `.main-nav`

Here is the JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/qixapariku/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

**`position:fixed` is in the way.** since it stands in the window area and totally of the flow, and of course unable to scroll as is

[If you want it to scroll](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wGqjXW)  you might set `fixed` to `absolute`

---

Another approach `absolute`, and `writing-mode`
you may take a look at writing-mode and still use transform to reverse direction:

```css
ul {
  white-space:nowrap;
  writing-mode:vertical-lr;
  transform:scale(-1,-1);
  padding: 1em 0;
  position:absolute;/* not fixed !! */
}
li {
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">METHODOLGY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TEAM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
```

you may also use `flex` and `row-reverse` : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/PNKeeq to bring home link at first/top.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. Row reverse seems really useful in situations like these.